# Independent memory channels: What does it mean for a programmer

Tags: memory-management, cpu, intel, internals, processors

I read the [Datasheet](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/xeon-e5-1600-2600-vol-1-datasheet.pdf) for an Intel Xeon Processor and saw the following:

> The Integrated Memory Controller (IMC) supports DDR3 protocols with four 
>   independent 64-bit memory channels with 8 bits of ECC for each channel (total of 
>   72-bits) and supports 1 to 3 DIMMs per channel depending on the type of memory 
>   installed.

**I need to know what this exactly means from a programmers view.**
The documentation on this seems to be rather sparse and I don't have someone from Intel at hand to ask ;)

1. Can this memory controller execute 4 loads of data simultaneously from non-adjacent memory regions (and request each data from up to 3 memory DIMMs)? I.e. 4x64 Bits, striped from up to 3 DIMMs, e.g:
   `| X |  _ | X | _ | X |  _ | X |`
   (X is loaded data, _ an arbitrarily large region of unloaded data)
2. Can this IMC execute 1 load which will load up to 1x256 Bits from a contiguous memory region.
   `| X | X | X | X | _ | _ | _ | _ |`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be implementation specific, depending on compiler, OS and memory controller. The standard is available at: http://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/docs/jesd-79-3d . It seems that if your controller is fully compliant there are specific bits that can be set to indicate interleaved or non-interleaved mode. See page 24,25 and 143 of the DDR3 Spec, but even in the spec details are light.

For the i7/i5/i3 series specifically, and likely all newer Intel chips the memory is interleaved as in your first example. For these newer chips and presumably a compiler that supports it, yes one Asm/C/C++ level call to load something large enough to be interleaved/striped would initiate the required amount of independent hardware channel level loads to each channel of memory.

In the Triple channel section in of the Multichannel memory page on wikipedia there is a small list of CPUs that do this, likely it is incomplete: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture

Comment: Thanks for the specification link.
But to make sure I get it right:
If say a QuadCore processor has such a memory controller and 4 threads (simultaneously) issue a load as shown in my example (1) - one 'X' per thread, which can lie far apart. Will the memory controller manage to read it from in parallel (=independently)? And each of those 4 requests can be served by up to 3 DIMMs (for TripleChannel)?

Comment: @Patrick If I understand the hardware correctly, all the loads will be checked against cache, then anything not existing there with be loaded in a serialized order into cache. I do not know what that order would be, I think it is also implementation specific. From the cache actual work would be done. Interesting things start to happen when the load request size exceeds that of the cache an one core is still working on freshly loaded data. Some CPUs empty the cache (forcing another load later) and load new stuff others wait. There is not always a correlation at this level to the coded logic.

Comment: @Squaky: That's of course true. 
Maybe I should rephrase: If the controller has those independent channels - can he load data for more than 1 load request at once? 
I wish to understand what "independent" means in this context. Does this give the controller parallelism to serve multiple requests at once (as opposed to serializing them with a queue)?

Comment: @Patrick It is my understanding that the memory controller acts as an abstraction layer to remove exactly those kinds of details from the developers hands. If the controller supports it I see no reason why it couldn't perform 2 different loads on 2 different channels or serialize them depending on design and the data to be loaded. However, I am not aware of a non-serialized memory controller in the wild. I did see one in an research setting that used gzip compression to reduce bandwidth consumption, so yeah anything could be done.